# How to install PostgreSQL with special version by Ansible role?

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I use the [ansible role](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-postgresql) installed PostgreSQL. Its default version is `10.6`. How to set another version to install? Such as `12.4`.

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.6
```

Comment: Maybe [here](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-postgresql/blob/master/vars/RedHat-8.yml#L2), but I can't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the variables `postgresql_version` and `postgresql_packages` since this role installs by default the Postgres versions that come on your OS(Check at the end of [role variable section](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-postgresql#role-variables) ) but you may need to change your package manager source list to point to the Postgres version that you want to install

```
- hosts: database
  become: yes
  roles:
    - geerlingguy.postgresql
      vars:
        postgresql_version: '12'
        postgresql_packages:
         - postgresql-12
         - postgresql-contrib
         - libpq-dev
```